# resize css property on absolutely positioned div?

Tags: html, css

My site is like this:

```
Left div   |  right div
```

Inside my left div, I have a position absolute element "custombox" that shows up over the "right div" (its got z-index:999), just because I want the code to be on the "left div side". My custombox has a css property "resize:both", which does not work. WHen I put a "position:relative" on my leftbox, then the position of my "custombox" is messed up and literally goes into "left div", which I don't want. How can I make my "custombox" resizable? (if absolutely needed, js plugins are okay)

```css
.leftdiv {
    background:red;float:left;width:50%;height:300px;
}

.custombox {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:50px;
    z-index:999;
    background:yellow;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    resize:both;
}

.rightdiv {
    background:blue;float:right;width:50%;height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="leftdiv">
        <div class="custombox">
            I like staying in the blue, but I want to be resizeable too.
        </div>
      He
    </div>

    <div class="rightdiv">
      blue
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle attached:
http://jsfiddle.net/axhqg20x/3/

Comment: Please use the code snippets available on here or link to a jsfiddle with what you have. Though, it is better to have the code in the answer, in which case you could also supply a fiddle

Comment: u want something like this https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `overflow` property of `.custombox` to **`scroll`** makes it resizable:

```
.custombox {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:50px;
    z-index:999;
    background:yellow;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    resize:both;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/axhqg20x/4/